# Special Characters iPad Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I wrote a monotouch app for the iPad that supports multiple languages. When I install the adhoc on my iPad one of my buttons reads 'Múltiple'. When another person here installs the same adhoc on an iPad with the same os version the same button reads 'M?ltiple'. Instead of the special 'u' it replaces it with a standard question mark. Again - exact same adhoc binary. Any ideas what is going on? We both seem to have identical language settings on our devices.

Comment: Does the other person have the same version of iOS installed? Different versions have different available fonts and not all font have all characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our translations come from a server and the local database had gotten corrupted somehow.